International Journal of Agriculture and Environmental Research
I am going to publish my research article in above journal. (ISSN: 2455-6939). But when I check impact factor, 2023 is not indexed and 2024 shows as under evaluation https://sjifactor.com/passport.php?id=20227
Can anyone help me with this? Is this good journal? this is my first article.

We do not offer reviews/rating of specific journals here.
